# BeautifulSoup scraping used car listings

Tags: python, html, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a program that scrapes listing of used cars from a website and outputs that car listing's link, its price, mileage and engine power. Right now it only repeats itself on the first listing. It should output every listing on the page.

The website is in Estonian, I hope that's not a problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata

url = 'https://www.auto24.ee/kasutatud/nimekiri.php?bn=2&a=100&b=7&ae=2&af=50&ssid=21570860'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'result-row'}):

    def getLink():
        find_link = soup.find('a', {'class' : 'main'})
        link = (find_link.get('href'))
        link_string = ('https://www.auto24.ee' + link)
        return link_string

    def getPrice():
        find_price = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'price'})
        price = (find_price.get_text())
        price_string = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", price)
        return price_string + ','

    def getMileage():
        find_mileage = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'mileage'})
        mileage = (find_mileage.get_text())
        return mileage + ','

    def getPower():
        engine = requests.get(getLink())
        kW_string = 'kW'
        engine_stats = BeautifulSoup(engine.text, 'lxml')

        if engine_stats.find(kW_string) != -1:
            power_find = engine_stats.find('tr', {'class' : 'field-mootorvoimsus'})
            power = power_find.find('span', {'class' : 'value'})
            power_string = power.get_text()
            return power_string
        else:
            return ('Engine power not specified.')

    print(getLink() + ',', getPrice(), getMileage(), getPower())
```

Outputs:

```
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3554965, 1600 €, 174 000 km, 1.8
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3554965, 1600 €, 174 000 km, 1.8
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3554965, 1600 €, 174 000 km, 1.8
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3554965, 1600 €, 174 000 km, 1.8
```

...and so on.

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata

url = "https://www.auto24.ee/kasutatud/nimekiri.php?bn=2&a=100&b=7&ae=2&af=50&ssid=21570860"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result-row"}):

    def getLink():
        find_link = div.find("a", {"class": "main"})  # <-- use div.
        link = find_link.get("href")
        link_string = "https://www.auto24.ee" + link
        return link_string

    def getPrice():
        find_price = div.find("span", {"class": "price"})  # <-- use div.
        price = find_price.get_text()
        price_string = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", price)
        return price_string + ","

    def getMileage():
        find_mileage = div.find("span", {"class": "mileage"})  # <-- use div.
        if find_mileage:  # <-- check if mileage exists.
            mileage = find_mileage.get_text()
        else:
            mileage = "N/A"
        return mileage + ","

    def getPower():
        engine = requests.get(getLink())
        kW_string = "kW"
        engine_stats = BeautifulSoup(engine.text, "lxml")

        if engine_stats.find(kW_string) != -1:
            power_find = engine_stats.find(
                "tr", {"class": "field-mootorvoimsus"}
            )
            power = power_find.find("span", {"class": "value"})
            power_string = power.get_text()
            return power_string
        else:
            return "Engine power not specified."

    print(getLink() + ",", getPrice(), getMileage(), getPower())
```

Prints:

```
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3554965, 450 €, 174 000 km, 1.8
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3563070, 450 €, 514 000 km, 1.9 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3564181, 500 €, 323 032 km, 1.6 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3563999, 500 €, 374 699 km, 1.8 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3550730, 500 €, 420 000 km, 2.0 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3550284, 500 €, 460 000 km, 2.0 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3564862, 525 €, 197 000 km, 1.6 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3554530, 525 €, N/A, 2.0 (96 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3565657, 650 €, N/A, 2.0 (100 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3562678, 650 €, 295 000 km, 1.8 (92 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3403673, 650 €, N/A, 2.0 V 6 (66 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3551361, 699 €, 230 000 km, 1.6 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3550824, 700 €, 223 000 km, 1.8 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3565138, 700 €, 282 740 km, 2.0 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3565734, 750 €, 330 000 km, 2.0 (107 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3521637, 850 €, 282 000 km, 1.8 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3545388, 899 €, 416 000 km, 1.8 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3556481, 900 €, 270 000 km, 2.4 (66 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3538068, 950 €, 170 300 km, 1.3 (44 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3544829, 950 €, 426 000 km, 2.0 (66 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3564562, 990 €, 478 800 km, 1.8 (66 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/1642523, 990 €, 173 123 km, 3.0 B/G (108 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3559696, 999 €, 315 000 km, 2.0 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3555474, 1000 €, 67 848 km, 1.4 (51 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3553789, 1000 €, 188 000 km, 1.6 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3554264, 1000 €, 235 000 km, 2.0 (81 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3555325, 1000 €, N/A, 2.0 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3473855, 1000 €, 260 000 km, 2.0 TDI (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3552728, 1000 €, 188 000 km, 2.0 (107 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3526023, 1000 €, 206 000 km, 3.0 (115 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3564811, 1099 €, N/A, 1.6 (80 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3543709, 1099 €, 291 000 km, 1.8 TDCi (66 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3546391, 1100 €, 394 514 km, 1.6 TDi (66 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3561075, 1100 €, 252 100 km, 1.8 tdi (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3565050, 1100 €, 235 000 km, 2.3 (107 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/2914584, 1100 €, N/A, 3.8 V6
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3545888, 1180 €, 183 800 km, 1.6 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3564541, 1200 €, 170 000 km, 1.6 TDI (66 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3564697, 1200 €, 128 000 km, 1.8 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3475104, 1200 €, 350 000 km, 2.3 (107 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3565359, 1200 €, 320 000 km, 2.0 TDI (96 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3517414, 1200 €, 295 000 km, 1.8 katalüsaator (92 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3557519, 1290 €, 125 000 km, 1.3 (51 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3529534, 1300 €, 199 500 km, 1.6 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3563109, 1320 €, 250 000 km, 1.8 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3511166, 1350 €, 161 400 km, 1.6 R4 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3537536, 1400 €, 401 779 km, 1.6 (85 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3296861, 1450 €, 245 000 km, 2.5 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3556460, 1475 €, 170 133 km, 1.6 (74 kW)
https://www.auto24.ee/soidukid/3559093, 1490 €, 296 300 km, 2.0 (85 kW)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at URL for page too there is change in URL so we can use that part `ak=0`,`ak=50` and so on to get the data according to web page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(0,150,50):
    print(i)
    res=requests.get(f"https://www.auto24.ee/kasutatud/nimekiri.php?bn=2&a=100&b=7&ae=2&af=50&ssid=21612624&ak={i}")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    main_data=soup.find("div",attrs={"id":"usedVehiclesSearchResult-flex"}).find_all("div",class_="description")
    for i in main_data:
        print(i.find("a",class_="main")['href'],end=" ")
        print(i.find("span",class_="engine").get_text(),end=" ")
        print(i.find("span",class_="price").get_text(),end=" ")
        try:
            print(i.find("span",class_="mileage").get_text())
        except AttributeError:
            print("NAN")
```

Ouput:

```
0
/soidukid/3554965 1.8 450 € 174 000 km
/soidukid/3563070 1.9 85kW 450 € 514 000 km
/soidukid/3564181 1.6 74kW 500 € 323 032 km
/soidukid/3563999 1.8 85kW 500 € 374 699 km
/soidukid/3550730 2.0 85kW 500 € 420 000 km
..
```